# Filling a remaining properties of class ASP .NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a serious problem, I have a class Client that have some properties that are columns of my database. First the user fill the form that corresponding to all properties except one. Then, I display lines of my database, and one column(property) have to be fill. So I don't how to proceed if I have to update, add ? 
Also I only know how to add the complete object client in the database and thus I don't know how to fill just one parameter.

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Client client)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Clients.Add(client);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return View(client);
    }

    return View(client);
}
```

**View**

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.compte)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.portefeuille)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.dateIn)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.dateOut)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.restriction_type)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.etat)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.decision)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
<input type="submit" value="SearchIndex" />
}
```

Thank you for you help !

It is ok for the update function:

[HttpPost]

```
    public ActionResult Update(IEnumerable<Client> model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            foreach (Client client in model)
            {
                db.Entry(client).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

But for the loop I have errors in the Model, it is not recognize and I don't know why

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.count ; i++)
```

{

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model[i].ID)

@Html.EditorFor(model => model[1].decision)

}

Thank you very much again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an extra property, which is not in your form?

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
     client.ExtraProperty = "MyValue";
     db.Clients.Add(client);
     db.SaveChanges();
     return View(client);
}
```

If you should only update, you should attach the object to entity framework, update the properties and call `db.SaveChanges();`

Comment: I have to fill it for the first time after having fill the other, is like a check property. Do I have to discard this check property in my class ?

Comment: Thank you for your help, but ExtraProperty isn't recognize

Comment: This is one used in my test, you need to change it to what your model needs.